# Strange behavior of Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc

I have regular servlets and Spring MVC dispatcherServlet defined in web.xml(co-existing). the mapping to Spring MVC's DispatcherServlet in web.xml is "/admin/*". I have a regular servlet making a request.getDispatcher().forward to a jsp under a folder structure "/admin/...". Since this is the internal forward, I expect the spring's dispatcherServlet won't get noticed. It turns out Spring's DispatcherServlet did noticed this forward and give me an excpetion for not finding the mapping to this JSP.

## anybody know what really happening here?

Update: I'm sorry I didn't make the question clearer:

We have an existing application without using Spring MVC. We decided to keep existing features as is and add Spring MVC in for any other new features.

so here is the web.xml mapping:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>springRouted</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:spring/mvc-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>4</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springRouted</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping> 
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>existingServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>existing.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

If the ExistingServelt calls request.getRequestDispatcher().forward("/admin/...jsp"), then Spring will report an error that not able to find mapping for "/admin/...jsp". It seems calling request.getRequestDispatcher().forward("/admin/...jsp") will make servlet container to recheck the web.xml and reroute through Spring's DispatchServlet.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong, mapping "/*" (star) means that you're mapping all extensions (.jsp, .js etc.) to dispatcherServlet.

Probably the simplest sollution is to make all @RequestMapping's have ".do" extension and map dispatcher servlet to "*.do", for example:

```
@RequestMapping("/myPage1.do")
public String getMyPage1() {
    // Some logic here

    return "myPage1";
}

@RequestMapping("/myPage2.do")
public String getMyPage2() {
    // Some logic here

    return "myPage2";
}

// And so on
```

Then you have to change your web.xml like this:

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/admin/*.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```